# PHP Pass multiple values to a foreach function

Tags: php, foreach

I am wondering how in PHP would I pass multiple arrays to a for each loop.

For example, in the following I'd want to pass both `$array1` and `$array2` to this for each loop, rather than have the for each loop written twice.

```
$array1 = somestring;
$array2 = someotherstring;

foreach ($array1 as $vals) {
    //do something cool
}
```

Edit: To clarify, I am aware that the array declarations are not valid. It is just a placeholder. That does not deserve a downvote. I want to run the entire foreach loop with $array1, and then run it again with $array2.

Comment: `$arrayForEach = array_merge($array1, $array2);`

Comment: This question cannot really be answered without you adding more information. It is fine that you want to handle both arrays inside a single loop. But you will have to tell us _how_ that is meant to be handled. Do you want one iteration over the elements of both arrays? Or separate iterations over both arrays? Or...

Answer (score 0):

```
$array3 = array_merge($array1, $array2);
foreach ($array3 as $vals) {
    // do your coolness
}
```

Comment: if your dont need $array3 for something else:  `foreach (array_merge($array1, $array2) as $vals) {`

Answer (score 0):

You can kind of **zip** two **indexed arrays** with `array_map(null, $array1, $array2)`. This way you will have a **list of [tuples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple)**, where the first element will be from `$array1` and the second - from `$array2`. You can iterate over this list and access both arrays elements in one iteration.

```
$array1 = [1, 2, 3];
$array2 = [1, 2, 3];

$zip = array_map(null, $array1, $array2);

foreach ($zip as $tuple) {
    echo $tuple[0], '-', $tuple[1], PHP_EOL;
}
```

Here is [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dfa4eca424befaf402eadd3fcbe776401b83a143).

Be aware that your arrays (in this case **lists**) have to be the **same length**. Other wise you will end up with broken [tuples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple), one elements of which will be `null`.

Comment: Hello, your answer is not exactly what I meant, but I did not clarify in my initial question. What I wanted to do was run the entire foreach loop with array1, and then run the entire loop again with array2. I apologize for not being clear.